# How to implement context menus on Matrial-UI DataGrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to implement context menus like this:
https://fancygrid.com/samples/miscellaneous/context-menu

But I can only achieve this so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-snow-pz1fr?file=/src/DataGridTest.tsx

The `contextmenu` event fired after clicking on a cell (or row).

But I want to immediately fire the `contextmenu` event.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onContextMenu` on the **parent**:

```
const onContextMenu = (e: React.SyntheticEvent): void => {
  let target = e.target as HTMLElement;
  console.log(target.innerHTML);
};
...
<div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }} onContextMenu={onContextMenu}>
...
```

[There](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-monad-yx2lb?file=/src/DataGridTest.tsx) is a demo.

Comment: Why didn't I think of this?  thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Chris Wong's answer, you can also do the following:

```
<DataGridPremium
        rows={rows}
        slotProps={{
          row: {
            onContextMenu: (e) => handleRowContextMenu(e),
            style: { cursor: 'context-menu' },
          },
        }}

        {...props}
      />
```

Then, you can get the row:

```
  const handleRowContextMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!event.currentTarget) {
      return;
    }
    const rowId = Number((event.currentTarget as HTMLDivElement).getAttribute('data-id'));

    const record = rows.find((row) => row.id === rowId);

    if (!record) {
      return;
    }
    
    // open a context menu
    setContextMenu(
      contextMenu === null ? { mouseX: event.clientX, mouseY: event.clientY, record } : null
    );
  };
```